# Reading and writing to a html file in aws s3 bucket using aws lambda (Python)

Tags: html, python-3.x, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am new to AWS and I am trying to retrieve a Html file from amazon s3 bucket and write to it using aws lambda python. I have tried using urllib to retrieve the html file but I am unable to write to it/update it. Currently the html file contains basic hello world text and I want to update it to post the current time of the server. Any suggestions how can I write to that file?

Thanks a lot,

```
import boto3
import urllib


def lambda_handler(event, context):

    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    response = s3.list_buckets()
    buckets = [bucket['Name'] for bucket in response['Buckets']]
    print("Bucket Name: %s" % buckets)

    bucket_url = urllib.request.urlretrieve("https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/testbucket/index.html","index.html")
    #print(index.html)

    #sock = urllib.request.urlopen("https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/testbucket/index.html") 
    #htmlsource = sock.read()

    #print(type(htmlsource))
    #print(htmlsource)



    from datetime import datetime   
    # TODO implement

    print(datetime.now().time())


    return 'Hello from Lambda'
```

Comment: Please format your code properly

Answer (score 1):

Just use the Python AWS SDK: https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html

https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/s3-example-download-file.html has an example on how to read the file.